# Extract a part of the JSON object in JAVA

Tags: java, json

This is the sample of a JSON object. I want to extract the part of it and display those values in a jTable (SWING) in JAVA. Keys as table column names and values as row data respectively.

```
[
   {
      "_id":{
         "date":"xxxxxxxx",
         "time":"xxxxxxx",
         "inc":"xxxx"
      },
      "DOCUMENTS":[
         {
            "EName":"John",
            "eAge":"25",
            "eAddress":"UK"
         },

         {
            "EName":"Alex",
            "eAge":"24",
            "eAddress":"Australia"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I want to extract this part.

```
      [
         {
            "EName":"John",
            "eAge":"25",
            "eAddress":"UK"
         },
         {
            "EName":"Alex",
            "eAge":"24",
            "eAddress":"Australia"
         }
      ]
```

I used this way to get the answer. Here jsonstring is the string that contains above data.

```
        String[] splits = jsonString.split("DOCUMENTS\":");
        String[] splits2 = splits[1].split("\\}]", 2);
        System.out.println("spilted  :"+splits2[0]);
```

but it is giving me the answer as

```
[{"EName":"John","eAge":"25","eAddress":"UK"}, 
 {"EName":"Alex","eAge":"24","eAddress":"Australia"
```

it removed the closed square bracket.

How can I get the correct answer? Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why not use a JSON Parser and get the `Documents` JSONArray?

Comment: You can use JSONPointer with the query: `/0/DOCUMENTS`

Comment: `it removed the closed square bracket` - Since u split on "}]" - `split2`

Comment: @MiteshPathak . I want to remove the last }] characters. How can I do it?

Comment: hmm... `int len = split1[1].length(); String ans = split1[1].substring(0, len - 3); // assuming last 2 chars are ] and }`

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this simple tutorials:
http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm

example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class KroplaTest {
    private static final String JSON = "{\"id\":{ "
            + "\"date\":\"xxxxxxxx\","
            + "\"time\":\"xxxxxxx\","
            + "\"inc\":\"xxxx\""
            + "},"
            + "\"documents\":["
            + "{"
            + " \"eName\":\"John\","
            + " \"eAge\":\"25\","
            + " \"eAddress\":\"UK\""
            + "},"
            + "{"
            + " \"eName\":\"Alex\","
            + " \"eAge\":\"24\","
            + " \"eAddress\":\"Australia\""
            + "} ]} ";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
            map = mapper.readValue(JSON, new TypeReference<HashMap<String,Object>>(){});
            System.out.println(map.get("documents").toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This will print to sysout:

```
[{eName=John, eAge=25, eAddress=UK}, {eName=Alex, eAge=24, eAddress=Australia}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `split()`, use:

```
int index= splits[1].indexOf("\\}]");
String result = splits[1].substring(0,index);
```